# Creating a Lion USB Drive from the Lion installer?

Tags: macos, install, usb

I have bought Lion on the AppStore and burned an installation DVD from the DMG file (and subsequently lost the DMG file).

Since DVDs are a bit clumsy and not available on all systems, I want to buy a 4 GB USB Stick and turn it into a Fresh Lion Installation DVD.

I found some questions about how to create a *Recovery* USB Drive, but I don't want recovery, I want a fresh install, like the Lion USB Drive on the Apple Store.

Is there a way to do that from the 10.6 DVD and the Lion download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply re-download Lion from the Mac App Store and then use Disk Utility to restore the DMG file to a USB stick.